# how to install spring framework in ecllipse keepler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have been searching for the download location but the official site of spring has no download link.

I downloaded zip file from http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/3.2.1.RELEASE/ . but it says me apache login error:error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at abs.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

I downloaded that login file also. but its still not working.

Can somebody provide me a sweet link for installing spring in ecllipse keepler.
Any site referral would be helpful. I could not find any other platform where this question will be valued except stackoverflow. So help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to eclipse.
2. Right click on the project you want to integrate spring with.
3. Go to Build Path--> Configure build path.
4. Under Libraries tab --> add external jars.
5. Add the jars from the the folder you have downloaded from spring site. (Inside "lib" folder you will get all the jar files).
6. Mainly you would be needing these jars- 
   -aop, context, context-support, aspect, expression, spring -webmvc, oxm etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't install the framework into the IDE -- you use it to program your Java application, which is independent of any IDE like Eclipse.

Secondly, Spring doesn't provide an all-in-one download link -- instead, you need to use a build tool like Maven or Gradle. This is so that all of the dependencies, such as the Apache logging library you also downloaded, can be automatically provided. Otherwise you would have to manage all of them yourself, and there are quite a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looking for spring tools support in eclipse
Follow these steps 
1) In eclipse , goto Help-->Eclipse Marketplace
2) Search for **STS**
3) You'll find **Spring Tool Suite(STS) For Eclipse Kepler (4.3)**
4) Click **Install** and follow the instructions
5) Finally it'll ask for **eclipse restart**

And you are done with the STS installation in Eclipse Kepler